# Display row of images only when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Could somebody please tell me how to make rows of images appear after clicking an achor tag (preferably) or a button. 
Basically, as you will see, on line 6 there is an  tag, which i would like to be able to press
so that 3 photos that are inside  would appear.
In other words :
Normally, the 3 photos are not visible, but once someone clicks on "Tapas", all 3 appear. If the anchor 
tag is clicked again, the 3 photos get hidden again.
If using an  for this is not possible,  one would work fine aswell.
Here is my HTML code :

```
<div class="grid-portfolio" id="portfolio">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="load-more-button">
                        <a href="#">Tapas</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <a href="images/menu_tapas_1_1.jpeg" data-lightbox="image-1"><div class="thumb">   
                        <div class="portfolio-item">  
                            <div class="image">
                                <img src="images/menu_tapas_1_0.jpeg">
                            </div>
                        </div></div>                  
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <a href="images/menu_tapas_2_1.jpeg" data-lightbox="image-1"><div class="thumb"> 
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                            <div class="image">
                                <img src="images/menu_tapas_2_0.jpeg">
                            </div>
                        </div></div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <a href="images/menu_tapas_3_1.jpeg" data-lightbox="image-1"><div class="thumb">
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                            <div class="image">
                                <img src="images/menu_tapas_3_0.jpeg">
                            </div>
                        </div></div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Thank you very much!!!
P.S. I know this code isn't the best, I just don't have the possibility of cleaning everything up right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

although i thought you should write code by yourself and if you stuck somewhere then you can ask , but if you are stuck from so much time then you can use this code

```
<style>
        .show-tapas{
            display: none;
        }
        .show-tapas.showing{
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="load-more-button">
                        <a href="#">Tapas</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row show-tapas">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <a href="images/menu_tapas_1_1.jpeg" data-lightbox="image-1"><div class="thumb">   
                        <div class="portfolio-item">  
                            <div class="image">
                                <img src="images/menu_tapas_1_0.jpeg">
                            </div>
                        </div>                 
                    </a>
                </div> 
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <a href="images/menu_tapas_2_1.jpeg" data-lightbox="image-1"><div class="thumb"> 
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                            <div class="image">
                                <img src="images/menu_tapas_2_0.jpeg">
                            </div>
                        </div></div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <a href="images/menu_tapas_3_1.jpeg" data-lightbox="image-1"><div class="thumb">
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                            <div class="image">
                                <img src="images/menu_tapas_3_0.jpeg">
                            </div>
                        </div></div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
    <script>
        var a = document.querySelector('.load-more-button');
        var b = document.querySelector('.show-tapas');
        a.addEventListener("click",function(e){
            e.preventDefault
            b.classList.contains("showing") ? b.classList.remove("showing") : b.classList.add("showing");
        })
    </script>
```

add style to first hide the row and then add script to show and hide the row .

Comment: It worked flawlessly, thank you!! One quick question though: after this section, theres 2 more just like it, and when I add that same code on the other two, nothing happens, as in the "button" doesnt do what you'd expect it to. What should I change to make it work for every single section?

Comment: look at the eventlistener line it is applied on just one button for multiple buttons with the same class you have to loop through all buttons array and add eventlistener ... you will have to learn the mechanism :)